# Adding column while importing to Access

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

**Situation:**
I am iterating through an Outlook-Mailbox and downloading all attachments into specific folders. Then I am iterating through the folders and import the CSV-Files into Access.

**Problem:**
I have the Outlook.MailItem.receiveTime property and the sender's name, which I have got from the File Title. I want to add those two pieces of information to each row of each CSV-File.

**Question:**
Is there a possibility to add those two columns on import or do I have to open each file and iterate through the content to add them?

*Little side question:*
Would it be possible to import the files directly from Outlook, meaning, without heaving to save them?

**Software and languages I use:**
    -Access 2013
    -Outlook 2013
    -VBA
    -SQL
    *Little side Information:* I am triggering all of this from an Access Form.

Comment: a) There's a built-in Export in Outlook (File/Options/Advanced) and b) there's a built-in import in Access (External Data/More/Outlook Folder). Have you seen any of these?

Comment: I haven't yet, can I use those in VBA?

Comment: Ok, I had a look at what you meant, but those tools don't really do the job for me, as they both export/import emails, but I only need the attachments/the information from the attachments.

Comment: If you have a way to identify the data from the CSV file after the import (e.g. the filename as a field, or import into a specific table) then you can use an update query after the import to provide those values to all of the rows imported.  (So that's one update statement per file, not adding it on each row).

Comment: I didn't think about that and that would work if not the field sender and time would be in the database already. So I could create it after the first import, but when I import the second table it would be there and because of the lack of fields in the CSV it would throw an error.
I could however, create a second table wich I import to and then insert it to the main table with the additional info. Could this work?

Comment: Adapting the CSV is possible but that will be fastidious. instead of that create another table "email" in Acccess and make the outlook VBA insert that table. You should have in it the 2 column missing plus an unique identifier for the CSV file. The access application should then join the email table with the csv table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through all CSV files and import each to a table.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Const strPath As String = "C:\your_path_here\" 'Directory Path
    Dim strFile As String 'Filename
    Dim strFileList() As String 'File  Array
    Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number

     'Loop through the folder & build file list
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
    While strFile <> ""
         'add files to the list
        intFile = intFile + 1
        ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
        strFileList(intFile) = strFile
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
     'see if any files were found
    If intFile = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
     'cycle through the list of files &  import to Access
     'creating a new table called MyTable
    For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelimi, , _
        "Test", strPath & strFileList(intFile)
         'Check out the TransferSpreadsheet options in the Access
         'Visual Basic Help file for a full description & list of
         'optional settings
    Next
    MsgBox UBound(strFileList) & " Files were Imported"
End Sub
```

If you want to download attachment from Outlook, try this.

```
Private Sub GetAttachments()

    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim FileName As String

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.Folders("MailboxName").Folders("Inbox")

    If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
                "Nothing Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each Item In Inbox.Items
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            If Atmt.Type = 1 And InStr(Atmt, "xlsx") > 0 Then
                FileName = "C:\attachments\" & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next Item

End Sub
```

Set a reference to MS Outlook and remember, the "MailboxName" is your email address.

Comment: Go ahead an mark this as an answer if it helps you.  I tried it, and it worked fine for me.